# Go XML Unmarshaling not reading attribute

Tags: xml, go

New to Go lang. From the XML, the code unmarshall all values except for attribute. Can someone please advise what I am doing wrong:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    v, _ := GetData()
    fmt.Print(v)
}


type Query struct {
    InstituationList []Instituation `xml:"institution"`
}

type Instituation struct {
    XMLName           xml.Name `xml:"institution"`
    OFXHomeID         string   `xml:"id, attr"`
    Name              string   `xml:"name"`
    FId               string   `xml:"fid"`
    FOrg              string   `xml:"org"`
    URL               string   `xml:"url"`
    OFXHomeIDD         string   `xml:"idd"`
}


func GetData() (*Query, error) {
    fakeXML := `
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
<institution id="A421">
<idd>423</idd>
<name>ING DIRECT (Canada)</name>
<fid>061400152</fid>
<org>INGDirectCanada</org>
<url>https://ofx.ingdirect.ca</url>
</institution>
</Data>
`

    content := []byte(fakeXML)

    e := new(Query)
    xml.Unmarshal(content, e)

    return e, nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. 
Apparently GO did not like the space in front of attr

It should be
OFXHomeID         string   `xml:"id,attr"`

instead of

OFXHomeID         string   `xml:"id, attr"`